# Cannot programmatically select radio button if preventDefault() called

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, preventdefault

I've got a 'catch 22' in Chrome. I cannot programmatically select a radio button within a `click` event if any other function bound to the same event makes a call to `preventDefault()`.

For example, I have a radio button with a parent element bound to a `click` event in which `preventDefault()` is called. If the radio button is clicked directly it is not checked. This is to be expected. However, I actually need the radio button to be selected so within code I attempt to check it in another function bound to the `click` event: `$(this).prop('checked', true);`.

Oddly, this doesn't work and I cannot remove the call to `preventDefault()` or disable propagation because it is in third party code that I need to run.

Is this a bug? Any suggested workarounds?

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/LnLuk4st/

### UPDATE:

I have tried @RGraham's suggestion. <strike>His example clearly works, but oddly it does not work in the context of my code</strike>. *@RGraham's code had a syntax error which made it appear to be working.*

Here's some context:

```
// Remember kendo tab
$(".k-tabstrip").each(function () {
    var $tabStrip = $(this);
    var $tabs = $tabStrip.find(".k-tabstrip-items .k-item");
    var tabCookie = "Current_Tab_" + $tabStrip.attr("id");

    // On tab change, set cookie
    $tabs.click(function () {
        createCookie(tabCookie, $(this).attr("aria-controls"), 1);
        $tabStrip.parent().css({ 'min-height': $tabStrip.parent().height() });


        if ($(this).is('input')) { // Doesn't eval to true, 'this' is always a '.k-item'.
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            // Never works if the input is clicked directly
            $(this).find('input').prop("checked", true);
        }


    });

    // @RGraham's suggestion...
    $tabs.on('click', 'input', function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", true); // Line reached but doesn't work either :(
    });

    // If cookie set, select tab
    var tab = readCookie(tabCookie);

    if (tab) {
        $tabs.each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("aria-controls") == tab) {
                $(this).click();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I haven't tried other browsers yet.

Comment: You're right, my solution did have a syntax error. Can't you use the Kendo API for this?

Comment: I possibly could, but it is the Kendo API applying `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still believe this behaviour to be a bug but I have found a workaround.

Capture the click of the radio button directly, prevent propagation, then programmatically click the parent of the radio button. This allows the third party code to run without applying `preventDefault` to the radio button.

```
    // preventDefault bug fix.
    $tabs.find("input").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().click();
    });
```